# Get latest record in Entity Framerwork Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I need to get the latest record in a table in my database, but I want to get it by Id.

For example - this is the data in my table:

```
ID   FK_CONTADOR   DATA
-----------------------
1    1             200
2    1             300
3    1             500
4    2             600
```

In MySQL, I solved it like this

```
select * 
from TABLE 
where Fk_CONTADOR = 1 
order by ID desc 
limit 1;
```

This is the result of the query:

```
ID   FK_CONTADOR   DATA
-----------------------
3    1             500
```

I want to solve it, but using Entity Framework Core. Help me please!

Comment: you can use Last or LastOrdefault in LinqToSql. Set your condition as predicate  expample : https://www.dotnetperls.com/lastordefault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward:

```
yourContext.Table
    .Where(t => t.Fk_CONTADOR == 1)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.ID)
    .FirstOrDefault() // or FirstOrDefaultAsync() with await
```

or with [query syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq):

```
 var query = from t in yourContext.Table
    where t.Fk_CONTADOR  == 1
    orderby t.ID descending
    select t;
 var result = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```